# Lisp return from function as argument to another

Tags: lisp

I have the following function that I want to call multiple other functions using their return values as parameters for the parent function.

This currently works:

```
(defun feet-to-m (A)
    (setf B (feet-to-inches A)) 
    (setf C (inches-to-cm B))   
    (setf D (cm-to-m C)))
```

I am wondering if Lisp has the ability to nest functions such that the following would work, or a more efficient way of doing this:

```
(defun feet-to-m (A)
    (cm-to-m (inches-to-cm (feet-to-inches (A)))))
```

Comment: just don't enclose `(A)` in parentheses: instead use `(cm-to-m (inches-to-cm (feet-to-inches A)))`. `(A)` means to call a function named `A`; without the parentheses it means to use A's value.

Comment: There are some wonderful books freely available which teach the very basics of Lisp. For example http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Edst/LispBook/

Comment: *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved."* This Q does that: it operates the notions of function call and chain of function calls. *"Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."* it does exactly that: includes attempted code. The only thing missing is the error message. So IMHO this Q should not be closed.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Also, if `(feet-to-inches A)` already works, why would you change it to  `(feet-to-inches (A))` in the second case?

Comment: @Will Ness: nesting function calls is available in many kinds of popular programming languages. Each Lisp intro touches that. He already ignored that he used undeclared variables, though SBCL would have complained about it.

Comment: the proper thing to do is to edit the error message in, so your Q won't be closed. After certain amount of negative record you may find yourself banned from being able to ask new questions on SO again. So do make your question up to par. -- @RainerJoswig CLISP doesn't complain at all.

Comment: @Will Ness: he originally tagged it SBCL. I removed it, because it is not an SBCL related question.

Comment: @RainerJoswig thanks for the clarification; I should've checked the edit history. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work almost as is. You just need to remove the parenthesis around `A`. Your intuition is right, that is exactly the paradigm that functional languages like Lisp are supposed to use. The first example you gave is more how you would code in an imperative language like Java, c++, etc.

```
(defun feet-to-m (A)
    (cm-to-m (inches-to-cm (feet-to-inches A))))
```